# Wrapping of node with different attribute in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt

I have input XML-document like this or different:

```html
<X3D version="3.2">
   <Scene>
      <Background skyColor="1 1 1"/>
      <Viewpoint position="0 0 4"/>
      <Transform DEF="body_0">
         <Inline url="body_0.x3d"/>
         <Transform DEF="body_1" translation="0,0.2,0">
            <Inline url="body_1.x3d"/>
            <Transform DEF="body_2" translation="0,0,0">
               <Inline url="body_2.x3d"/>
               <Transform DEF="body_3" translation="0,0,0">
                  <Inline url="body_3.x3d"/>
                  <Transform DEF="body_4" translation="0.5,0,0">
                     <Inline url="body_4.x3d"/>
                     <Transform DEF="body_5" translation="0,0,0">
                        <Inline url="body_5.x3d"/>
                     </Transform>
                  </Transform>
               </Transform>
            </Transform>
            <Transform DEF="body_6" translation="0,0,0">
               <Inline url="body_6.x3d"/>
               <Transform DEF="body_7" translation="0,0,0">
                  <Inline url="body_7.x3d"/>
                  <Transform DEF="body_8" translation="0.5,0,0">
                     <Inline url="body_8.x3d"/>
                     <Transform DEF="body_9" translation="0,0,0">
                        <Inline url="body_9.x3d"/>
                     </Transform>
                  </Transform>
               </Transform>
            </Transform>
         </Transform>
      </Transform>
   </Scene>
</X3D>
```

I need to wrap node with certain attribure DEF to one more node . For example, attribute calculates in variable $find. So I have xslt-stylesheet:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="find" select="concat('body_','3')"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//Transform" 
        group-adjacent="@DEF = $find">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
            <Transform rotation="1 0 0 1.57">
              <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
            </Transform>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope to see output document whith next code:

```html
<X3D version="3.2">
   <Scene>
      <Background skyColor="1 1 1"/>
      <Viewpoint position="0 0 4"/>
      <Transform DEF="body_0">
         <Inline url="body_0.x3d"/>
         <Transform DEF="body_1" translation="0,0.2,0">
            <Inline url="body_1.x3d"/>
            <Transform DEF="body_2" translation="0,0,0">
               <Inline url="body_2.x3d"/>
               
            <Transform  rotation="1 0 0 1.57">
               <Transform DEF="body_3" translation="0,0,0">
                  <Inline url="body_3.x3d"/>
                  <Transform DEF="body_4" translation="0.5,0,0">
                     <Inline url="body_4.x3d"/>
                     <Transform DEF="body_5" translation="0,0,0">
                        <Inline url="body_5.x3d"/>
                     </Transform>
                  </Transform>
               </Transform>
            </Transform> 
               
            </Transform>
            <Transform DEF="body_6" translation="0,0,0">
               <Inline url="body_6.x3d"/>
               <Transform DEF="body_7" translation="0,0,0">
                  <Inline url="body_7.x3d"/>
                  <Transform DEF="body_8" translation="0.5,0,0">
                     <Inline url="body_8.x3d"/>
                     <Transform DEF="body_9" translation="0,0,0">
                        <Inline url="body_9.x3d"/>
                     </Transform>
                  </Transform>
               </Transform>
            </Transform>
         </Transform>
      </Transform>
   </Scene>
</X3D>
```

but stylesheet has not any effect or there is too much nodes.
I understand that a lot depends on the parameters that I specify in the select attribute, but I still have not been able to find the solution
How can I rich it?

Next I try to give an examplse of use it.
In the following code I use a list of strings that is formed in tamplate "getlistOfBodies"

```html
<xsl:variable name="listOfBodies">
        <xsl:call-template name="getlistOfBodies">
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      
      <xsl:template match="*[Transform]">  
        <xsl:call-template name="wrap">
          <xsl:with-param name="search" select="$listOfBodies" /> 
            <!-- examples of $listOfBodies: "'body_2', 'body_5','body_6'" -->
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="wrap" > 
    <xsl:param name="search" select="0"/>
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:for-each-group select="* | @*" group-adjacent="@DEF = $search">
    <!-- ... ->
```

So I want to see next output depending on the $search:
(let $search = "'body_2','body_6'")

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <X3D version="3.2">
        <Scene>
          <Background skyColor="1 1 1"/>
          <Viewpoint position="0 0 4"/>
          <Transform DEF="body_0">
             <Inline url="body_0.x3d"/>
             <Transform DEF="body_1" translation="0,0.2,0">
                <Inline url="body_1.x3d"/>
       
                <Transform rotation="1 0 0 1.57">
                   <Transform DEF="body_2" translation="0,0,0">
                      <Inline url="body_2.x3d"/>
                      <Transform DEF="body_3" translation="0,0,0">
                         <Inline url="body_3.x3d"/>
                         <Transform DEF="body_4" translation="0.5,0,0">
                            <Inline url="body_4.x3d"/>
                            <Transform DEF="body_5" translation="0,0,0">
                                    <Inline url="body_5.x3d"/>
                                </Transform>
                         </Transform>
                      </Transform>
                    </Transform>
       </Transform>
       
       <Transform rotation="1 0 0 1.57">
                   <Transform DEF="body_6" translation="0,0,0">
                      <Inline url="body_6.x3d"/>
                      <Transform DEF="body_7" translation="0,0,0">
                         <Inline url="body_7.x3d"/>
                         <Transform DEF="body_8" translation="0.5,0,0">
                            <Inline url="body_8.x3d"/>
                            <Transform DEF="body_9" translation="0,0,0">
                               <Inline url="body_9.x3d"/>
                            </Transform>
                         </Transform>
                      </Transform>
                   </Transform>
                </Transform>
                
             </Transform>
          </Transform>
       </Scene>
    </X3D>
```

If $search = "'body_2','body_3'" then should be wrap two nodes (DEF='body_2', DEF='body_3') with two different Translates. If the number of strings in the variable is 6, then six nodes should be wrap with six Transforms.
It's something like this...

Comment: Do you expect the input to have more than one `Transform DEF="body_3" ` element or why do you need that grouping code? Your sample has only one such element and if all you need is wrap that into a new parent you can simply write a template matching that element.

Comment: It will be different DEFs, a list of DEFs in fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use your grouping at the right level and handle the rest by the identity transformation (for instance in XSLT 3 with `xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"`) then you get

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="search" as="xs:string">body_3</xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[Transform/@DEF = $search]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="@DEF = $search">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                <Transform rotation="1 0 0 1.57">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </Transform>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>              
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Based on your comments and edits it sounds as if you don't want to wrap adjacent elements at all but simply want to wrap certain elements into a new `Transform`, as the following code does:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="def-list" as="xs:string*" select="'body_2','body_3'"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Transform[@DEF = $def-list]">
      <Transform rotation="1 0 0 1.57">
          <xsl:next-match/>
      </Transform>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the parameter is now a sequence of strings (`xs:string*`) and any `Transform` element having a `DEF` attribute equal to one of the values in the sequence is wrapped into a new `Transform` element.

Online sample at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMeu

Comment: it's nice! If I want to wrap several nodes, can I specify several values inside the param?

Comment: It would be easy to turn that parameter into a list of strings but I am not sure that helps as so far I have not understood how your input can look and in which way you want to wrap elements. You might better edit your question and explain with some more text and examples what kind of grouping and wrapping you want to perform.

Comment: A list of strings is a engenius way to wrap certain <Transform> elements. But if I use list " 'body_2', 'body_6' " (it's sibling elements) then wraps both in common Transform. Probably it's because they was taken in common current-group() by for-each-group select=" * ". How can I wrap  'body_2', 'body_6' separately?

Comment: Can you edit the question and show samples of the input and output you want together with the parameters you will pass in (i.e. the DEF values)? I am still not sure whether you need the grouping at all (you don't need it to wrap any `Transform[@DEF = $search]` into a new parent) or whether you at least expect to have several e.g. sibling elements with DEF as `body_3` that need a common wrapper element. Also with various DEF values passed in, will that be a finite and known list when writing the code or can that be dynamic?

Comment: Done! And yes, list can be dynamic

Comment: @goshanoob, see the edited answer, it does not try to group and wrap siblings at all but simply wraps any element having a DEF attribute equal to one item in the parameter list into a new `Transform` element.